# How to nest jQuery .when calls with callbacks?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, asynchronous

I have a function that loads a section.

```
function loadSection(sectionId, onLoaded) {
    $.when(
        loadTemplate(sectionId),
        // etc
    )
    .then(function () {
        // removed for brevity
    }
}
```

In the `loadTemplate` function I fade out the current template, and after the fadeout I load the new template.

```
function loadTemplate(sectionId) {
    // Fade out current template.
    return $content.fadeOut(function () {
        // After fade out, load new template via ajax.
        $.ajax({
            url: settings.apiUrl + 'GetSectionTemplate',
            data: { sectionId: sectionId },
            type: 'post',
            success: function (template) {
                // Add new content and fade in new template.
                $content
                    .html(template)
                    .fadeIn();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The problem is that the `$.when` only waits for the fadeOut function to finish before moving on. I need it to wait for both the fadeOut and the ajax call to finish, but I need the ajax call to execute only after the fadeOut finishes.

Comment: What if you `return $.ajax({});` ?

Comment: @ianpgall The return returns from the fadeOut callback function. I tried that. It doesn't fix anything.

Comment: Your loadTemplate function needs to participate in the deferred/promise world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a deferred object, return it, and then resolve it when the ajax completes:

```
function loadTemplate(sectionId) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    $content.fadeOut(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: settings.apiUrl + 'GetSectionTemplate',
            data: { sectionId: sectionId },
            type: 'post',
            success: function (template) {
                $content.html(template).fadeIn();
                deferred.resolve();
            }
        });
    });
    return deferred;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use an `Array` to push the *Promise objects into* and return that. Like

```
function loadTemplate(sectionId) {
    var promises = [ ];

    // Fade out current template.
    promises.push($content.fadeOut());
    promises.push($.ajax({
        url: settings.apiUrl + 'GetSectionTemplate',
        data: { sectionId: sectionId },
        type: 'post',
        success: function (template) {
            // Add new content and fade in new template.
            $content
                .html(template)
                .fadeIn();
        }
    }));

    return promises;
}
```

and then call it like

```
$.when.apply( null,
    loadTemplate(sectionId)
).then(function() {
});
```

If you need more control over the order of promise-objects resolve or you want to intercept / filter results, you can also use `.pipe()` to somewhat *concat* the promises.

Comment: What's the `, //etc` after `loadTemplate(sectionId)` for? You've already supplied an array containing all the arguments for the `.when`, no?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: copy&paste failed.

Comment: This actually doesn't work because the ajax call does not get added to the array until the fadeout completes. Meanwhile the array has already been handed up to `$.when.apply()`. I will try to put together a jsFiddle to show the issue.

Comment: @AlexFord: then just move the `.ajax()` to the same *level* as the `.fadeOut`. Should do the trick.

Comment: @AlexFord Here's the fiddle to save you the trouble: http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/3GvDb/1/

Comment: You can't move it to the same level because `.when` does not care about the order of the calls passed into it, only that they all finish before executing `.then`. It would fire off the fadeout and the ajax at the same time pretty much. It would not make the ajax wait for the fadeOut. All it cares is that both the fadeout and ajax finish before moving into `.then`

Answer (score -1):

Try making your ajax call synchronous:

```
 $.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: settings.apiUrl + 'GetSectionTemplate',
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: It *may* be a "fix" by forcing the fadeOut's callback to be a synchronous action, but there's most surely a better way around.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté yes, it falls in the category "ugly hacks" but sometimes those are the only way, not stating this is the case..

Comment: that is most likely the worst solution available.